# promise generic assignment

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Please see the code [here](http://goo.gl/I5ZHa2) (also listed at the end of this post)

I am not sure why the `get` function is not strongly typed.

it is defined as `get:(id:string) => IPromise<Test>;`

but, I am assigning to it as

```
    constructor(srv:Store<TestData>){
        this.get = (id) => this.getImp(srv, id);
    }

    private getImp(srv:Store<TestData>, d:string) {
        return srv.get("/test")
            .then( (d) => { //d == IPromise<getImp>
                var rep = d.reply; //rep == TestData
                //var rep:string = "" gives error
                return rep;
            });
    }
```

`getImp` returns a prmise (result of get) with a typed parameter `TestData`. But this should not be compatible with `Test`, hence with `get`. Why there is no error?

there is no error if I change the signature of `getImp` as

`private getImp(srv:Store<TestData>, d:string):IPromise<TestData> {`

how `getImp(srv:Store<TestData>, d:string):IPromise<TestData>`  is assignable to   `get:(id:string) => IPromise<Test>`

anything wrong with the definition of IPromise ?

thanks.

### full source

```
export interface IGetResult<T> {
    reply: T
}

export class Store<T>{
    get:(r:any) => IPromise<IGetResult<T>>;
}

 export interface TestData {
    Id:         string
    Name    :   string
}
export interface ITest extends TestData{
    test():void
}

export class Test implements ITest {
    Id:string;
    Name:string;
    test(){}
}
export class service{
    get:(id:string) => IPromise<Test>;

    constructor(srv:Store<TestData>){
        this.get = (id) => this.getImp(srv, id);
    }

    private getImp(srv:Store<TestData>, d:string):IPromise<TestData> {
        return srv.get("/test")
            .then( (d) => { //d == IPromise<TestData>
                var rep = d.reply; //rep == TestData
                //var rep:string = "" gives error
                return rep;
            });
    }
}


 //==========  angular.d.ts  ===========
 // from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts

  export interface IRequestConfig {
        method: string;
        url: string;
        params?: any;

        // XXX it has it's own structure...  perhaps we should define it in the future
        headers?: any;

        cache?: any;
        withCredentials?: boolean;

        // These accept multiple types, so let's define them as any
        data?: any;
        transformRequest?: any;
        transformResponse?: any;
        timeout?: any; // number | promise
    }

 export   interface IHttpPromiseCallback<T> {
        (data: T, status: number, headers: (headerName: string) => string, config: IRequestConfig): void;
    }


export interface IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T> {
        data?: T;
        status?: number;
        headers?: (headerName: string) => string;
        config?: IRequestConfig;
    }

export interface IHttpPromise<T> extends IPromise<T> {
        success(callback: IHttpPromiseCallback<T>): IHttpPromise<T>;
        error(callback: IHttpPromiseCallback<T>): IHttpPromise<T>;
        then<TResult>(successCallback: (response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>) => TResult, errorCallback?: (response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>) => any): IPromise<TResult>;
        then<TResult>(successCallback: (response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>) => IPromise<TResult>, errorCallback?: (response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T>) => any): IPromise<TResult>;
    }

    export interface IPromise<T> {
        then<TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => IHttpPromise<TResult>, errorCallback?: (reason: any) => any, notifyCallback?: (state: any) => any): IPromise<TResult>;
        then<TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => IPromise<TResult>, errorCallback?: (reason: any) => any, notifyCallback?: (state: any) => any): IPromise<TResult>;
        then<TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => TResult, errorCallback?: (reason: any) => TResult, notifyCallback?: (state: any) => any): IPromise<TResult>;


        catch<TResult>(onRejected: (reason: any) => IHttpPromise<TResult>): IPromise<TResult>;
        catch<TResult>(onRejected: (reason: any) => IPromise<TResult>): IPromise<TResult>;
        catch<TResult>(onRejected: (reason: any) => TResult): IPromise<TResult>;

        finally<TResult>(finallyCallback: ()=>any):IPromise<TResult>;
}
```

Comment: The `then` argument `d` wouldn't be a `IPromise<Test>`, but the `Test` only

Comment: I am wrong. but, it would be IGetResult<TestData>, no??  `.then( (d:IGetResult<TestData>) => { //d == IPromise<TestData> ` still, the question remains, why there is no error

Comment: Yeah, `(srv.get("/test"):IPromise<IGetResult<TestData>>).then( (d:IGetResult<TestData>) => { // d == IGetResult<TestData>`. I cannot answer the actual question unfortunately, as I don't know about TypeScripts type inference capabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics in TypeScript are of different design. In some cases they're bivariant WRT their type parameter, and you're expecting that they're covariant in this particular case. Promises are immutable so afaik they should indeed be covariant wrt the type they're holding.

To see that its so, change

```
export interface ITest extends TestData
```

to

```
export interface ITest
```

then remove the property `Name:string;` from `class Test`. If you do this, then typescript will finally complain that it "Cannot convert `IPromise<TestData>` to `IPromise<Test>`" because neither `Test` can be derived from `TestData` nor `TestData` can be derived from `Test`.

A more direct illustration of this bug:

```
var x: IPromise<Test> = <IPromise<TestData>><any>{}
```

As long as Test inherits from TestData *or* TestData inherits from Test, this remains valid.

---

Explanation of the terms covariant and bivariant

A generic type is covariant WRT its type parameter if its hierarchy varies together with the hierarchy of the type parameter. Example:

If

- `Array<T>` is *covariant* WRT the type `T` and
- `ExtendedItem` is a subtype of `Item`

then

- `Array<ExtendedItem>` is accepted as a subtype of `Array<Item>`.

A generic type is bivariant WRT its type parameter if the subtyping goes both ways:

If

- `Array<T>` is *bivariant* WRT the type `T` and
- `ExtendedItem` is a subtype of `Item`

then

- `Array<ExtendedItem>` is accepted as a subtype of `Array<Item>` and
- `Array<Item>` is accepted as a subtype of `Array<ExtendedItem>` and

Final note: To be type-safe, a mutable Array should actually be *invariant* WRT to the argument. Many languages such as C# or Java make it covariant - but in this case its possible to `push(item:OtherExtendedItem);` into an array of `ExtendedItem` without it being caught as an error at compile time.

---

Edit: what does "sometimes bivariant" mean though? It means that typescript doesn't actually have any hard-coded variance rules. When it encounters a specialization of a generic type, it just applies that type parameter. After it does that, it performs a structural check of the resulting types - if they match, then everything is okay. Consider the following example:

```
class Box<T>{   
    public x: number;
    constructor(t:T) {
        this.x = 1;         
    }
}
interface AB  { a: number; b: number; }
interface ABC { a: number; b: number; c: number; }

var ab:Box<AB> = new Box({a: 1, b: 2});

var y:Box<ABC> = ab;
```

The compiler considers this code valid. Whether the type has been specialized with T = AB or T = ABC doesn't change the structure of the resulting type, which is simply {x: number}

What happens if we have a method in Box that returns a Box? Lets add that method and see:

```
getThis():Box<T> { return this; }
```

Again, if we apply the specialization, we get an infinite, recursive structure:

```
{x: number, getThis: () => {x : number, getThis: () => ... }}
```

that ends up being the same regardless of the specialization.

But, if we add another method instead, one that retuns a value of type T:

```
getValue():T { return <T>{}; }
```

Then if we apply the specialization T = AB, it results with the following structure:

```
{x: number; y: () => { a: number; b number; } }
```

which is incompatible with the specialization T = ABC

```
{x: number; y: () => { a: number; b: number; c: number; } }
```

and the compiler will finally complain.

At this point, you may notice that `IPromise<T>` isn't really quite like `Box<T>`. Indeed, it does not have a method that returns a value of type T, but it has methods (like `then` and `catch`) that take callbacks which take values of type T. Lets add a method like that to Box

```
then<U>(f: (val: T) => Box<U>): Box<U>;
```

Now lets apply the type specialization `T = AB`

```
{x: number; then: (val: {a: number; b: number;}) => Box<{x: number; then: ...}}
```

and `T = ABC`

```
{x: number; then: (val: {a: number; b: number; c: number;}) => Box<{x: number; then: ...}}
```

These should not be compatible!

Which leads us to the true problem in TypeScript: arguments of function type ("callbacks") are bivariant WRT their input arguments, when they should be contravariant.

Here is a simple example that demonstrates the problem:

```
interface IA { bar(): void }
interface IB { bar(): void; foo(): void; }

function fn(passedFn: (a: IA) => void) {
  var a:IA = {bar: function(){}}; 
  passedFn(a); 
}

// compiles but throws TypeError at runtime!
fn((b: IB) => b.foo());
```

In this example, a callback that takes an argument of type IA cannot be safely substituted with a callback that takes an argument of type IB (when IB extends IA). Like in the example, the callback taking the argument of type IB may try to call the method foo(), which means that passing an argument of type IA to that callback will result with a type error

---

The quickest fix for your issue would be to find a member to IPromise that returns a value of type T:

```
export interface IPromise<T> {
   __bivariance_fix: T;
}
```

Of course this will make the interface incompatible with other promise types (or libraries), so the real fix here is for TypeScript to correct behavior of callbacks.

Comment: What's covariance and contravariance and how do they apply here :P?

Comment: I just saw the comment by Anders on this article http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2013/04/23/playing-with-generics-in-typescript-0.9.0/ . He says `our type system is structural and generics are co-variant—but since parameters are naturally contra-variant, in aggregate they end up being bi-variant` . I am not sure what he meant by `since parameters are naturally contra-variant` . Does your answer true with this comment from the language designer?

Comment: Oops no, my answer is not entirely correct. Apparently the rules are more complicated than what I believed, and generics only remain bivariant until they get a member field of the input type T, or a function that returns a value of that type. I'll have to edit and update my answer.

Comment: Just a note: combining covariant and contravariant restrictions should result with invariant, not bivariant generics. The reason why they are bivariant is that there was no way to  model event listener types otherwise (but that was before string types and union types)